# How to bind error for form fields in Angular 8 app?

Tags: angular

I have a subscribe block where I am able to catch a custom error object which sent
back from spring boot.

```
.subscribe((data) => {            
},
(err) => {
  //console.log(err);
  let httpErrorResponse: HttpErrorResponse = err;
  let errorResponse: ErrorResponse = httpErrorResponse.error;
  console.log(errorResponse);
  if (errorResponse != null && errorResponse != undefined 
      && errorResponse.errors != null) {
     errorResponse.errors.forEach(error => {
        console.log(error.field_bame + " " + error.message);
        let fieldName = error.field_bame;
        let message = error.message;
        listingFormDirective.form.controls['${fieldName}'].setErrors({'existCompany': true});         
    }) 
  }
  
});
```

What I'm trying to do here is to have genreic method (util class) to bind each field for error for all the Angular applciation.
the problem is here:

```
form.controls['${fieldName}']
```

I tried also:

```
   form.controls[fieldName]
```

The error from the consule:

```
core.js:7187 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setErrors')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use back-ticks instead of single quotes

for ex:

```
form.controls[`${fieldName}`]
```

Comment: thanks, I'll try this tomorrow, actually I found the I need to send company_name and not companyName. Anyway try this tomorrow and wil create another question on getting the @JsonProperty name.